# If Statement Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I can't to solve my problem anymore, please , I am looking to make a selection but only if the date is lower than 11/05/1990  must take  01/01/2000 and make the selection

```
select (date, champ1 , champ2, champ3, 
CASE
when (a.date <'1990-05-11') then (a.date ='2000-01-01') 
else a.date 
END as a.date 
from table a
```

Comment: *Don't* use localized strings. Use a date-typed field, date-typed parameters or the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. BTW what's the type of `a.date` ? YOu won't be able to perform range queries *at all* if it contains localized strings

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos   
I just want to make the selection on the date field of the table at, I don't want to add another field, should I leave the word CASE? , I just want to do the research if the date is lower than 11/05/1990 it takes 01/01/2000

Comment: The reason localized strings always fail is that *strings* are always sorted alphabetically. This means that `'11/05/1990'` comes *after* `'01/01/2000'` - never mind the ambiguity between eg November 5th vs May 11th. You can only perform range queries if *all* strings follow a sortable format like `YYYY-MM-DD`. It's far faster, easier and safer though to use `date`

Comment: Your logic does not seem to make much sense.  Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Finally, your query doesn't make a selection (as in restrict the results), it *replaces* all values that come before a certain string with another (with some syntax errors). Is that what you really want? That should be `CASE WHEN a.date<'....' then '.....' ELSE a.date END as Date`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 
for example if I made from the date 11/05/1990 I have 30 results, but if I take that from the date 01/01/2000 I have only 10 results, it's just a selection

Comment: Not with the query you posted. This will always return *all* results, replacing older dates with a hard-coded value. It's not just a selection. And doesn't work either - you simply can't perform date comparisons with *text* unless the format is *very* specific. Post a sample of your data and your desired output. And make sure you use `date` both for the field *and* the parameters

Comment: select  (date,  champ1 , champ2, champ3, 
 CASE
when (a.date <'11/05/1990') 
then (a.date ='01/01/2000') 
else a.date
END as a.date
from table a

Comment: @JAVAINMYDNA you already posted that in the question. It's invalid syntax and an invalid comparison. The answer shows the *correct* syntax and comparison, if you really want to replace dates

Comment: Perhaps "_make the selection_" means OP wants this in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CASE like that. If you want to replace certain values dynamically with something else, you need to return that *value* in the THEN part, not a comparison (which returns a boolean).

The following assumes that `a.date` is defined with the data type `date`

```
select date, champ1, champ2, champ3,
       case 
           when a.date < DATE '1990-05-11'  
               then DATE '2000-01-01'
           else a.date
       end as "date"
from table a
```

Comment: Thanq All , just i have erreur  ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"  in ligne FROM

Comment: @JAVAINMYDNA not with this answer's query. There's no `;` here. What did you actually try?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  ,no no , that near of inner join ,because there is jointure :)

Comment: @JAVAINMYDNA: there is no join in my answer.

Comment: @JAVAINMYDNA not in the query you posted. There's no JOIN in the question. People can't guess what the problem is with code you haven't even posted.